# Mission to Mars beginning meaning

Tags: plot-explanation, mission-to-mars

Some months ago I watched **Mission to Mars** and in the first part of the movie you see that the astronauts are killed by a large vortex generated from the humanoid base.
In the end you'll see that the aliens help humans to understand their origin, after the transmission of the pair of missing chromosomes code.
Isn't this contradictory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that the "aliens" were waiting for the correct response to their signal. If they got the wrong response, their response was the vortex. The reasoning for this was because if the responders could not understand the message and respond accordingly, then they would not be getting the rest of the information. It's a sort of a *if you aren't ready for it, you aren't getting it* situation. Towards the end of the movie, the astronauts (Gary Sinise and crew) then give the correct response and so are allowed to survive to receive the rest of the answer.

Comment: I'm not really sure about this. I think that it would be a lot better to simply don't do anything if the message is not ok or if it's not there. It's like: "You're not enough intelligent, you should dieeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee". It reminds me to Rambo and not an extraterrestrial creature with that kind of kindness.

Comment: @DavidePastore: I don't think you're wrong, but let's not pretend this film was a work of art. There was a helluva lot wrong with it and I'd say this is one of those things.

Comment: I didn't think it was "are you intelligent enough", I thought it was "Are you human" As only humans (or someone with knowledge of the human base pairs) would know the correct response.

Comment: @DavidePastore ... I took it as a protection mechanism against unwelcomed guests, not as a genocide feature against stupid beings.